# Converting dataframe series column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe containing a datetime column ('created_at') of type : series. I need to convert this column into datetime format in order to perform some groupby operations on it.

Here is the dataframe structure:

```
           id                created_at                                          full_text 
0  1286763394658381824  ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']  عدم إصابتك بفايروس كورونا حتى الان مؤشر لأمرين
1  1240341918967459840  ['2020-03-18T18:18:52Z']  رسالة مسربة من داخل #سجن_العقرب تؤكد على تفشى 
2  1243387711995572224  ['2020-03-27T04:01:46Z']  في الافلام الاجنبيه نشاهد امريكا تقود العالم ل
3  1317384182012792832  ['2020-10-17T08:37:19Z']  هناك الكثير من الاكاذيب والفبركات حول لقاح كور
4  1317404463859142656  ['2020-10-17T09:57:55Z']  @kasimf لقاح كورونا ليس هدفه الإضرار بالبشر إن
5  1242851102258868224  ['2020-03-25T16:29:28Z']  بعد تفشي المرض في إيطاليا ولا وجود علاج قرر جم
```

I tried different ways to convert 'create_at' column into datetime format but noneone worked. Here is an example :

```
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    df['date'] =parse(df['created_at'].astype(str))
```

This give me the following error:

```
    raise TypeError('Parser must be a string or character stream, not '
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series
```

**Edit**

I figured out this by doing :

```
from dateutil import parser
def convert_date(date_str):
        return parser.parse(date_str) 
        
df['date']= df['created_at'][0][2:-2]    
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(convert_date)
```

Thanks to you all

Comment: use pd.to_datetime; `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This gave me the following error : raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']

Comment: you can also define the format: `pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)`.

Comment: ...or take first element from the lists: `pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str[0])`

Comment: The second suggestion also didn't work : ValueError: time data '['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z' (match)

Comment: And the third one gave me this : in parse
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: [

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created at'], format="['%Y-%M-%DT%H:%M:%SZ']") Looks like the proper format

Comment: Thanks. This looks more close to the solution. But it gave me this error : ValueError: 'D' is a bad directive in format '['%Y-%M-%DT%H:%M:%SZ']'

Comment: the correct format has a lower case z; `%z`, not `Z` and not `%Z` (upper case).

Comment: [mre]: `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z'],['2020-03-18T18:18:52Z']]).str[0])` works fine

Comment: When I try to replace this by the 'created_at' column : df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str[0])    It gives me this error :  raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: [

Comment: then unfortunately, the example you show in your question is not reproducible - what is the actual content of df.created_at ?

Comment: When I do print(df.dtypes) . I get this :  id  int64 | created_at                object |
full_text                 object

Comment: The content of created_at is as show in the question, values like : ['2020-03-18T18:18:52Z']

Comment: I can't answer, because the question has been flagged as already answered on another post. Yet, the other post, I don't believe answers this question.

The problem here is that each value in created at, is a list with 1 element. So this should do the trick:
```pd.to_datetime(df.created_at.apply(lambda x: x[0]))```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
```

Comment: from the OPs example, it seems to me that `created_at` is a pandas Series, you your code won't work.

Comment: Thanks. However it looks like the suggestion contain a syntaxical error. I am getting this :NameError: name 'created_at' is not defined

Comment: I think conversion should be something like this:

     df['date'] =df['created_at'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

Comment: no it was ```df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']) ```

Comment: @ilhank still didn't solve it . It gave me this : dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']

Comment: @finix Same here. I am getting this :  raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']

Comment: what about this one  ? df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format="['%Y-%M-%DT%H:%M:%SZ']")

Comment: @ilhank Same :( .  I am getting this : raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']

Comment: ```pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z'],['2020-03-18T18:18:52Z']]).str[0])```

Comment: @finix This works. But when  I try to replace this by the 'created_at' column : df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str[0]) It gives me this error : raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr) dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: [

Comment: can you try this  df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'],infer_datetime_format=True)

Comment: @ilhank It still give me the same error :  raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: ['2020-07-24T20:41:14Z']

Comment: This ignores the fact that `created_at` is a columns with a list of strings on each element.